# Should I use the verb "class" or "classify"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Which should I use, and what is the difference?

> The stages of sleep are **classed** as non-rapid eye movement (NREM) and rapid eye movement (REM) sleep.
>
> The stages of sleep are **classified** as non-rapid eye movement (NREM) and rapid eye movement (REM) sleep.

Comment: You can use either, both are synonyms.

Comment: I just had a thought: that "to class" is to "class" as "to classify" is to "classification". While a "class" is a group, a "classification" is a grouping. Perhaps there should be a distinction if there is currently none?

Comment: There *is* a distinction between the *words* 'class' and 'classify'. They do not *always* mean the same thing. The *meaning* of those words as used in the example sentence, however, may be the same.

Comment: Absent any other context which prefers one or the other, "classify" is the more idiomatic choice, though either can be used.  (Mainly if you referred to the stages of sleep as "classes" then "classed" would be most appropriate.  Otherwise, "classified" is more suitable for a general division into categories which are not explicitly referred to as "classes".)

Answer (score 1):

**Class** is a noun that has been used as a verb since around 1642 (see Peter Shor's excellent comment below). However, **Classified** is preferable in this instance, especially when written. 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class

A seasonal example of the annoying trend of making verbs out of random nouns is **"gifting."**
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gifting

Comment: The verb *class* has been around since 1642, much longer than its more-recently-coined synonym *classify*, which regrettably slipped into British usage somewhere around 1776 (according to the OED).

Comment: I am justly rebuked.

Comment: I agree with you that the best word to use today is *classify*, but I wanted to set the historical record straight.

Comment: I do not know if I am right but in my humble opinion "to classify" can also be used in meaning "to keep something at secret", however, "to class" is just a division into categories.